# Weex: How to set screen orientation

Tags: nat, weex

looking for a Weex way to set screen orientation to landscape. Seems like the [NAT orientation API](http://natjs.com/#/reference/device/screen?id=orientationstatuscallback) simply says what the orientation is. Is this something that should be done in the respective Android or iOS builds?

Answer (score 0):

as API document says `weexpack plugin add nat-device-screen` this is enough.